# Sorting Column in R

Tags: r

I have data that includes a treatment group, which is indicated by a 1, and a control group, which is indicated by a 0. This is all contained under the variable treat_invite. How can I separate these and take the mean of pct_missing for the 1's and 0's? I've attached an image for clarification.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3geLM.png)

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "*How can I separate these and include the rest of the data?*" Are you just trying to sort a dataset so all the 0's are together, then all the 1's?

Comment: Yes, but I want to take the mean of pct_missing of only the 1's and the mean of pct_missing of only the 0's

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data frame is called `df`:

```
df <- df %>% group_by(treat_invite) %>% mutate(MeanPCTMissing = mean(PCT_missing))
```

Or, if you want to just have the summary table (rather than the original table with an additional column):

```
df <- df %>% group_by(treat_invite) %>% summarise(MeanPCTMissing = 
mean(PCT_missing))
```